# visual studio c++ project consistantly restarting once

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Whenever I start my command line, debug executable, whether using the debugger within visual studio or on its own, it always restarts once. It is the weirdest thing: I start it, it seems to be running and I can interact with it, but then a few seconds later it just restarts on its own. And this happens only once; the .exe that opens the second time is stable and will keep on running until I stop it. Any ideas on what is going on here? I tried googling the issue but not sure exactly what to search for!

Comment: You need to be more specific about what is going on and also show any information you have gathered in your *own* investigations into this problem.

Comment: This could be your antivirus program. Disable your AV and see if it happens again. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25631427/487892

Comment: @drescherjm, yes! that was totally it

Comment: @drescherjm if you add your comment as an answer I'll accept it instead of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @drescherjm commented, the issue was my antivirus. Disabling it fixed the issue.