# Text game opens in C++ opens twice

Tags: c++

So, I'm making a text game. It opens and works fine then will abruptly close with no apparent trigger and open a new instance of itself. After it does this once it does not do it again. If I'm doing other things stupidly I would also like to know this. Heads up that this is a lot of code because I do not know where the problem lies. I tried to cut out the non important bits though. Would also like to know how to read write files in another directory that isn't the root one the exe is in. I am using Code::Blocks to compile. If the header files are important I can include them.

```
//#libraries

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "windows.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "time.h"
#include "Dungeon.h"

using namespace std;
//functions
int roomLogic();
void stats();
void options();
void devConsole();
void tutorial();
//Choose Class functions
void chooseClass();
void choosePaladin();
void chooseWarlock();
void chooseRanger();
void chooseWarrior();
void chooseRogue();
//global variables
int textSpeed;
int turns = 0;
bool debug = false;
//Player Stats
//Name and Such
int kills = 0;
int killScore = 0;
int damageDelt = 0;
int damageTaken = 0;
int score = 0;
string name;
string Class;
string race;
//Items
int keys = 0;
int money = 10;
int moneySpent = 0;
//Combat
int att = 10;
int def = 10;
int speed = 10;
int sneak = 10;
int eva = 10;
int perc = 10;
int accuracy = 10;
int health = 100;
int maxHealth = 150;
int mp = 50;
int magicPower = 10;

int main()
{
  cout << "WHOLE BUNCH OF INTRO TEXT THAT YOU DO NOT NEED TO READ BECAUSE  
  THERE IS A LOT" << endl;
  Sleep(1000);
  //Text Speed Definition
  cout << "How do you like your text speed? 'Slow', or 'Fast'?" << endl;
  cout << "Type your answer and press ENTER to send" << endl;
  string textSpeedInput;
  cin >> textSpeedInput;
  bool success = false;
  //a while statement to get them to say yes no and set a text speed, not   
  important


  cout << "If you have never played the game before and would like a   
  tutorial, type \n'tutorial' if not type 'no'" << endl;
  string tutor;
  cin >> tutor;
  bool tut = false;
  //another while statement thing that I cut out the function literally just     
  couts
  chooseClass();
  stats();
  roomLogic();
  system("PAUSE");
  exit(0);
  return 0;
}

void chooseClass()
{
  cout << "Choice is fun, but randomness can be too, Would you like to 
  choose your class   and race(Yes) or get a random class and race(No)" <<  
  endl;
  string willChoose;
  cin >> willChoose;
  if(willChoose == "Yes" || willChoose == "yes")
  {
    cout << "Would you like to be a:\n" << endl;
    cout << "Paladin (+3 Defense, -1 Speed)," << endl;
    cout << "Warlock (+3 Magic Power, -1 Defense)," << endl;
    cout << "Ranger (+2 Accuracy, +1 Perception, +1 Speed, -2 Defense)," << 
    endl;
    cout << "Warrior (+2 Attack, +1 Defense, -1 Magic Power), or" << endl;
    cout << "Rogue (+2 Stealth, +1 Attack, +1 Evasion, +1 Speed, -3 
    Defense)?" << endl;
    bool hasChoosen = false;
    cin >> willChoose;
    //another cut out while statement
```

code has broken by this point. I have no clue why. Please help is it an augment I need in my int main or something?
Here is an example read write I use just so you know:

```
 ifstream x_file (".filenamehere.txt"); x_file >> variable to change; 
 x_file.close();
```

And to write:

```
 ofstream y_file (".filename.txt"); y_file << thing to write; y_file.close();
```

Comment: ***It opens and works fine then will abruptly close with no apparent trigger and open a new instance of itself.*** Are you using avast? This looks like the sandbox feature of avast.

Comment: If that is the case, how do I disable it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25783514/487892

Comment: Is there anyway for this to be seen as safe to other users because I would like other people to be able to download this when I'm done with it.

Comment: There is nothing you can do with your code to make Avast stop doing this (if you could virus writers would have a way to defeat the protection). The good thing is however if you do not change the executable and run it a second time you should not get the execution in the sandbox (so no double execution of your application).

Comment: It doesn't do that sadly, maybe my program changes itself or something. Otherwise I'd have it launch once and save a file saying it has launched once